# openAPI 3.0 is not showing try it out button for API endpoints

Tags: node.js, api, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I've configured my api with swagger openapi3.0, unfortunately, it is not showing try it out button for my API endpoints. am I missing any configuration in the swagger file? can anyone help me how to solve this error?[image: here is the link to screenshot]

Note: I'm using swagger open API3.0
here is the configuration I've used:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "Reinvent-API",
    "description": "Reusable and minimalistic API for Hyperledger-fabric Networks",
    "contact": {
      "name": "Dev",
      "email": "dev@gmail.com",
      "url": "https://dev.github.io/"
    },
    "license": {
      "name": "MIT",
      "url": "https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"
    }
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:3000/api"
    }
  ],

  "paths": {
     "/invoke": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
      "API Explorer"
    ],
        "description": "invoke chaincode function",
        "operationId": "invoke",
        "requestBody": {
          "description": "body parameters should be passed as the order defined in chaincode function. First argument must be function name to call.",
          "required": true,
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/invoke"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Chaincode Invoke Succesfull.",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/invoke"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
   "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "invoke": {
        "properties": {
          "fcn": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "arg1": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "arg2": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Here is the express configuration I've used.

```
var express = require('express');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express')

swaggerDocument = require('./swagger.json');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
var options = {
  swaggerOptions: {
    supportedSubmitMethods:["get", "post"]
  }
};

app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument, options));
```

Or maybe it should be posted to swagger-ui github as a bug?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Looks like CORS needs to be enabled?

Comment: I'm able to fix it by updating `swagger-ui-express` npm module to latest version

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to add a `description` to the server. Something like this

```
"servers": [
 {
  "description": "Local env",
  "url": "http://localhost:3000/api"
 }
]
```

Comment: Tried it Radu Dita. No luck.